# How to delete a historical git commit

Tags: git

Saying that I've execute `git add --all && git commit` twice. So for now my local git repository contains two new commits: A and B.

If I execute `git push`, I will push both of them.

How can I push only the newer commit, which is B? In other words, is it possible to remove the commit A without touching the commit B?

Comment: You can do a `git rebase` and skip the commit you don't want.

Comment: It's fundamentally impossible to remove A while keeping B and leaving it untouched. B keeps track of its parent. It specifies that its parent is A. `git rebase`, as Jaa-c commented, may work, but it works by creating a *new* commit which doesn't specify A as its parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to push to master. I would cherry pick the commit I want to deliver:

```
git fetch
git checkout -b delivery_branch origin/master
git cherry-pick B
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

The short and rather unsatisfying answer is "you can't".  Commit B inherently depends on commit A because A is B's parent commit.

What you *can* do is stop using commit B at all.  Construct a third commit—call it C—whose parent is the parent of A, and whose content is whatever content you want.  (This could match B's content, for instance, or not.)  Then move the *name* of the branch so that instead of pointing to commit `B` (which points back to `A`, which points back to older commits), the name points to new commit C:

```
       B--A   [no longer on your branch - abandoned in favor of C]
      /
...--o--C   <-- branch
```

You can now `git push origin branch` to push commit C, without using commits A and B at all.

(Note that the precise mechanics for *making* commit C depend on what snapshot you want to have attached to C.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your log is like this :

```
Z--A--B
```

Where A is the commit you want to remove and B is the commit that you want to preserve. Also assume that 'dev' is the name of this branch.

Then, (with A,B and Z representing the respective commit IDs):

1. Create a temporary branch say, 'temp', from the commit Z.

   ```
   git checkout -b temp
   git reset --hard Z
   ```
2. Cherry-pick the commit B to temp. (Resolve conflicts if any)

   ```
   git cherry-pick B
   ```
3. Go back to your branch (dev in this case), and remove A and B

   ```
   git checkout dev
   git reset --hard Z
   ```
4. Merge temp branch into your branch (dev)

   ```
   git merge temp
   ```
5. Delete the temp branch

   ```
   git branch -d temp
   ```

**Note:**

1. The commit ID of B will change as we are cherry-picking.
2. If you have A and B in your remote branch, then you will have to push with the force option.

   ```
   git push -f
   ```